# Automate to add key value pairs in function app configuration

Tags: azure-devops, terraform, jenkins-pipeline, devops, terraform-provider-azure

Is there a way to get the secrets used in functions code for function app without adding them manually in appsettings configuration of function app on azure.

Is there a possibility to add key value pairs in configuration of function app?

I would like to have best solution other than pulling from keyvaults

Comment: please provide the code details that you tried?

Comment: Why do you want a different solution than 'pulling from Key Vault'? This is one of the better solutions available. If you do not want to code getting the values, have a look at how to [Use Key Vault references for App Service and Azure Functions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/app-service-key-vault-references?tabs=azure-cli).

Answer (score 0):

There are of course other ways of implementing a secret in your function.
You could put the secrets in clear text in your variables, but Microsoft recommends KeyVault cause its the only really secure option.

Please let us know what code/language you are using and what you want to do with the secret.